# Linq query filter with “contains” with list<T> multiple properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i'm using entity framework with dot net framework

as example i have student class like

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

when i need to search for students in many departments i can do it like the following

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student{Age = 12,DepartmentId =1 },
    new Student{Age = 11,DepartmentId =2 },
    new Student{Age = 11,DepartmentId =3 },
    new Student{Age = 13,DepartmentId =4 },
};
// get all department ids
var departmentIds = students.Select(s => s.DepartmentId);
var studentList = DbContext.Students.Where(s=>departmentIds.Contains(s.DepartmentId)).ToList();
```

this will generate SQL query like

```
  Select StudentId , Age , DepartmentId , Name
  From Students where DepartmentId in (1 , 2 , 3 , 4)
```

**My question**

i need to search for any student match any item in students list 
like the following query

```
Select StudentId , Age , DepartmentId , Name
From students 
Where 
    (departmentId= 1  and age = 12)
    OR
    (departmentId= 2  and age = 11)
    OR
    (departmentId= 3  and age = 12)
    OR
    (departmentId= 4  and age = 13)
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you write that out?

Answer (score 2):

Store the age per department and write

```
var departmentAge =
    departments.ToDictionary(d => d.DepartmentId, d => d.RequiredAge);
```

and then

```
.Where(s => departmentIds.Contains(s.DepartmentId) &&
            s.Age == departmentAge[s.DepartmentId])
```

The second part is not translatable to SQL. You might have to separate it with `AsEnumerable` or join the two tables in the query to get something like

```sql
Select s.StudentId, s.Age, s.DepartmentId, s.Name
From Students s inner join Departments d
where s.DepartmentId in (1 , 2 , 3 , 4) and s.Age = d.RequiredAge
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Henk Holterman's comment, just write it out

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student{Age = 12,DepartmentId =1 },
    new Student{Age = 11,DepartmentId =2 },
    new Student{Age = 11,DepartmentId =3 },
    new Student{Age = 13,DepartmentId =4 },
};

var studentList = DbContext.Students.Where(s=> (s.DepartmentId == students[0] && 
                s.Age == students[0]) || (s.DepartmentId == students[1] && s.Age == 
                students[1]) || (s.DepartmentId == students[2] && s.Age == 
                students[2]) || (s.DepartmentId == students[3] && s.Age == 
                students[3])).ToList();
```